# Need to check the check box automatically when enter anything in the textarea of html editor

Tags: html, css, extjs4

i need the code when i type anything the text area of the HTML editor then the other check box automatically checked. can you help me

here the sample extjs code.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
bodyPadding: 10,
width: 300,
title: 'Pizza Order',
items: [
    {
    xtype: 'htmleditor',
    enableColors: false,
    enableAlignments: false,
    listeners: {
                render: function(){
                  this.textareaEl.on('keyup', function() {
                        var notes = this.textareaEl.getValue();
                        if(notes.length > 0) {   Ext.getCmp('checkbox1').setValue(true);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Ext.getCmp('checkbox1').setValue(false);
                        }

                  });

                }
            }
    },
    {
        xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
        fieldLabel: 'Toppings',
        defaultType: 'checkboxfield',
        items: [
            {
                boxLabel  : 'Anchovies',
                name      : 'topping',
                inputValue: '1',
                id        : 'checkbox1'
            }
        ]
    }
]   
renderTo: Ext.getBody()
```

});

Is this correct way to do it. can anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did your manager told its not the correct way ?

Comment: If it works, perfect. For style and best practices it would be better to post your code at [SO codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Really great place. :)

Comment: Why is this tagged with jQuery?

Comment: @Sarath Saleem Please help me iis it wrong or not. I edited the thing

Comment: @winner_joiner Please help me iis it wrong or not. I edited the thing

Comment: In your code you should check on keyup event not in keydown event. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src='./js/jquery-1.10.2.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#my_textarea').keyup(function(){

            if($('#my_textarea').val().length>0)
            {
                $('input#my_checkbox').prop('checked', true);
            }
            else
            {
                $('input#my_checkbox').prop('checked', false);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input id='my_checkbox' type="checkbox"/><span>Some data here</span>
<textarea id="my_textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3bUDx/) to jsFiddly.

Comment: I have edited the above code. can you help me now. i cannot able to login and edit in JSFiddle. so i edited the same question.

Comment: what is extjs version?

Comment: i am using extjs version 4.2

Comment: First of all you have mistake in your jsFiddle testcase [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sSK6w/3/). Second this.textareaEl gives following error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined ` Where are you defined it?

Comment: Before `renderTo: Ext.getBody()` put `,`

Comment: Thanks but the corrected code not work properly. i need to check the checkbox while typing in the htmleditor